# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'Synchronized'

Tags: python-3.x, synchronized, consumer, producer, multiqueue

```
if math.fabs(time.time()-start_time) > time_interval :
```

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'Synchronized'

Code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time =  multiprocessing.Value( 'd', 0.0)
    time_t = multiprocessing.Value('d', 0.005)
    producer(all_client, q[0], time_t, start_time, t)
```

...

```
def producer(sequence, output_q, time_interval, start_time, t):
    start_time = t = time.time()
    for item in sequence:
        time.sleep(random.expovariate(glamda[0]))
        item.time_arrived = item.V_entered[0]= time.time()
        output_q.put(item)
        
        if math.fabs(time.time()-start_time) > time_interval :
            print("producer time out ", time_t)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to get. But you can resolve this error by just get the value from Synchronized object (this is not float, you may extract value from this object).
replace:
`if math.fabs(time.time()-start_time) > time_interval`
to:
`if math.fabs(time.time()-start_time) > time_interval.value`